# Android - How to capture RTP packet

Tags: java, android, sockets, rtp

I can view the streaming video from Darwin Streaming Server on Android using `VideoView` class.

I just need to get the sequence number field in an RTP packet to measure Packet Loss Rate.

Could you give me general idea of how to capture an RTP packet?.

Is that socket programming? Please tell me the proper step if possible.

Comment: Have you resolved the issue if yes please share the solution. I am also facing the same problem. any pointer will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Yes. I solved that last year. Sorry, it's quite late. Here is the hint: http://jnetpcap.com/. Or you can download here: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ijoua5em6cfg6lj/MzteCn_9m6 (put this in src/org/jnetpcap) Also you need libjnetpcap.so. https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjnhcn77id3lfa0/libjnetpcap.so. Sorry I can not send you my project. But I believe this is enough for you

Comment: @ngubk the dropbox links are dead.Pls can you send the new ones again?

Comment: @TranNguDang link shared is now landing to some junk site. Can you please update?

Answer (score 0):

tcpdump on Android - https://www.androidtcpdump.com/

watching/capture live traces

adb exec-out "tcpdump -i any -U -w - 2>/dev/null" | wireshark -k -S -i -

https://blog.wirelessmoves.com/2017/02/adb-and-tcpdump-on-android-for-live-wireshark-tracing.html